# Saving a Entry Tkinter box to a text file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a Entry box:

I have created a text file:

```
   
    save_file.close()


However the data being entered is not saving to the text file. This is being saved:
```

Accounts
<bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>><bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry2>>

```
Any idea on how to fix this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the get method.

Change

```
save_file.write(str(username_input_box.get))
```

to

```
save_file.write(str(username_input_box.get()))
```

As you are having trouble, I have written out a very basic version of your program which I have tested and it works. It writes the "Accounts" text to the file and when the button is pressed, it writes the content of the entry field to the file too. If you code still isn't working, perhaps you'll need to post a more complete and executable example of your code

```
from tkinter import *


def creating_text_file():   
    save_file = open("Accounts.txt", "a")   
    title = "Accounts"   
    line = "\n"   
    save_file.write(title)    
    save_file.write(line)   
    save_file.close()

def apending_to_text_file():     
    save_file = open("Accounts.txt", "a")
    save_file.write(str(username_input_box.get()))
    save_file.write("\n")
    save_file.close()

root = Tk()
username_input_box = Entry(root, width=30)
username_input_box.grid()
btn = Button(root,text="Press Me",command=apending_to_text_file)
btn.grid()
creating_text_file()

root.mainloop()
```

As an improvement, I'd use the context managers to open/close your file. They look like this

```
with open("Accounts.txt", "a") as save_file:
    save_file.write("Some random text")
    #No need to close the file as the context manager does this for you
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working, when I open the text file nothing is saved there and there is no error message. Any ideas? xx

Comment: Do you know how to get a button to have 2 commands? x

Comment: @Katie010203 Sounds like a topic for another question. Multiple topics in one question are frowned upon